# Mathjax Stoke and Fill color value in genrated SVG is currentColor

Tags: svg, mathjax

When I convert below expression in SVG

```
<math style="line-height:10em;color:red;" xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'>
  <mrow>
    <mfrac><mn>1</mn><mn>2</mn></mfrac>
    <msub><mi>m</mi><mn>1</mn></msub>
    <msubsup>
      <mi>u</mi>
      <mn>1</mn>
      <mn>2</mn>
    </msubsup>
  </mrow>
  <mo>+</mo>
  <mrow>
    <mfrac><mn>1</mn><mn>2</mn></mfrac>
    <msub><mi>m</mi><mn>2</mn></msub>
    <msubsup>
      <mi>u</mi>
      <mn>2</mn>
      <mn>2</mn>
    </msubsup>
  </mrow>
</math>
```

Stroke and fill color values are currentcolor in output

```
 <svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="-webkit-transition-property: none; color: red; vertical-align: -1.13ex; display: inline; line-height: 10em; " width="17.114ex" height="3.384ex" viewBox="0 -970.7 7368.4 1457.1" role="img" focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" computedstyle="font_style:normal;font_weight:normal;font_variant:normal;width:136px;height:27px;text-align:left;font-size:16px;margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;text-indent:0px;vertical-align:-9px;line-height:160px;" amzn-node-id="34" >
               <defs id="MathJax_SVG_glyphs" style="-webkit-transition-property: none; display: inline; " computedstyle="font_style:normal;font_weight:normal;font_variant:normal;width:0px;height:0px;text-align:left;font-size:16px;margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;text-indent:0px;vertical-align:baseline;line-height:160px;" amzn-node-id="35" >
                  <path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-31" d="M213 578L200 573Q186 568 160 563T102 556H83V602H102Q149 604 189 617T245 641T273 663Q275 666 285 666Q294 666 302 660V361L303 61Q310 54 315 52T339 48T401 46H427V0H416Q395 3 257 3Q121 3 100 0H88V46H114Q136 46 152 46T177 47T193 50T201 52T207 57T213 61V578Z" style="-webkit-transition-property: none; display: inline; " computedstyle="font_style:normal;font_weight:normal;font_variant:normal;width:0px;height:0px;text-align:left;font-size:16px;margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;text-indent:0px;vertical-align:baseline;line-height:160px;" amzn-node-id="36" ></path>

               </defs>
               <g fill="currentColor" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 0)" style="-webkit-transition-property: none; display: inline; " computedstyle="font_style:normal;font_weight:normal;font_variant:normal;width:0px;height:0px;text-align:left;font-size:16px;margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;text-indent:0px;vertical-align:baseline;line-height:160px;" amzn-node-id="51" >
                 code removed for brevity 
               </g>
            </svg>
```

> fill="currentColor" stroke="currentColor"

Ideally it should be #FF0000 for red.
How can i fix this problem or is it expected behavior from MathJax.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct output for MathJax.  Note that the `<svg>` element has `color: red` in its `style` property, which (when the SVG is used in a web page), will cause the `currentColor` to be red.  But if you load the SVG as a separate file, the browser may not process the `style` attribute.

There are several ways to work around that.  One would be to use the `mathcolor="red"` attribute instead of `style="color:red"`, since MathML provides `mathcolor` specifically for that:

```
<math mathcolor="red" xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'>
...
</math>
```

Alternatively, you could use an `<mstyle>` element to set the math color internally:

```
<math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'>
  <mstyle mathcolor="red">
  ...
  </mstyle>
</math>
```

Either of these will make an SVG that has the color set internally rather than through the SVG's `style` attribute.